# How to GROUP one record from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, record, group-concat

I have two tables lesson and subjects. It is a one to many ratio as in each lesson can be categorized under 1 or more subjects resulting in something like "Name" subject: math, science, social studies

This would return 3 records:
Name, math
Name, science
name, social studies

This results in my looping through and combining and messes up my search count
How can I get one record with all three instead? So my search count is accurate and I don't need extra PHP code to check if name is the same and gather the extra subject?

I've tried basic

```
SELECT * FROM lesson INNER JOIN subjects ON subject.id = lesson.subject
```

But this results in 3 entries

***EDIT***
My query is more complicated than I lead on. I have a middle table keeping tracking of the two tables above and their relation
This query is for searching. Here's what I have.

```
SELECT name, subject        
FROM lesson As l
INNER JOIN lesson_sub As ls
  ON ls.lesson_id = l.id
INNER JOIN subjects As s
  ON s.id = ls.subject_id
WHERE CONCAT(l.name, s.subject) LIKE '%KEYWORD%' AND s.id = SUBJECT_ID
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/) to give you utility methods that implement this sort of thing for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GROUP_CONCAT() function with your JOIN query:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

> GROUP_CONCAT(expr)
>
> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
>   values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.
>   The full syntax is as follows:
>
> GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
>                [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
>                    [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
>                [SEPARATOR str_val])
>
> mysql> SELECT student_name,
>       ->     GROUP_CONCAT(test_score)
>       ->     FROM student
>       ->     GROUP BY student_name;
>
> Or:
>
> mysql> SELECT student_name,
>       ->     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score
>       ->               ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
>       ->     FROM student
>       ->     GROUP BY student_name;

So:

```
SELECT lesson.name, GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.name SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM lesson JOIN subjects ON (subject.id = lesson.subject)
    GROUP BY lesson.name;
```

**TEST**

```
CREATE TABLE lesson ( name varchar (20), subject integer );
CREATE TABLE subjects ( id integer, name varchar(20) );

INSERT INTO subjects VALUES ( 1, 'Math' ), ( 2, 'Physics' ), ( 3, 'Chemistry' );

INSERT INTO lesson VALUES ( 'Lesson A', 1 );
INSERT INTO lesson VALUES ( 'Lesson A', 2 );
INSERT INTO lesson VALUES ( 'Lesson A', 3 );
INSERT INTO lesson VALUES ( 'Lesson B', 2 );
INSERT INTO lesson VALUES ( 'Lesson B', 3 );
INSERT INTO lesson VALUES ( 'Lesson C', 1 );

SELECT lesson.name, GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.name SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM lesson JOIN subjects ON (subjects.id = lesson.subject)
    GROUP BY lesson.name;

+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| name     | GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.name SEPARATOR ', ') |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| Lesson A | Math, Chemistry, Physics                   |
| Lesson B | Chemistry, Physics                         |
| Lesson C | Math                                       |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**MORE COMPLICATED TEST (with intermediate table)**

```
CREATE TABLE lesson ( id integer, name varchar (20) );
CREATE TABLE subjects ( id integer, name varchar(20) );
CREATE TABLE lesson_sub ( lesson_id integer, subject_id integer );

INSERT INTO subjects VALUES ( 1, 'Math' ), ( 2, 'Physics' ), ( 3, 'Chemistry' );
INSERT INTO lesson VALUES ( 1, 'Lesson A' ), ( 2, 'Lesson B' ), ( 3, 'Lesson C' );

INSERT INTO lesson_sub VALUES (1,1), (1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1);

SELECT lesson.name, GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects
    FROM lesson_sub JOIN lesson ON ( lesson.id = lesson_sub.lesson_id )
                    JOIN subjects ON (subjects.id = lesson_sub.subject_id)
    WHERE CONCAT(lesson.name, subjects.name) LIKE '%Chem%'
    GROUP BY lesson.name;

SELECT name, subjects FROM (
    SELECT lesson.name, GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjects
    FROM lesson_sub JOIN lesson ON ( lesson.id = lesson_sub.lesson_id )
                    JOIN subjects ON (subjects.id = lesson_sub.subject_id)
    GROUP BY lesson.name ) AS lesson_clear
    WHERE CONCAT(name, subjects) LIKE '%Chem%';

+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| name     | GROUP_CONCAT(subjects.name SEPARATOR ', ') |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| Lesson A | Chemistry                                  |
| Lesson B | Chemistry                                  |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----------+--------------------------+
| name     | subjects                 |
+----------+--------------------------+
| Lesson A | Physics, Math, Chemistry |
| Lesson B | Physics, Chemistry       |
+----------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Im getting  Invalid use of group function query when using GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Post the query you're using. Updating my answer with a test case.

Comment: Works great! Only difference is I have many columns to select and if i do SELECT * on the outter select it's fine, but if i do CONCAT(*) LIKE then it doesn't work. Any idea to CONCAT all fields returned from inner select?

Comment: I tried lesson_clear.title and that works but CONCAT(lesson_clear.*) does not, weird

Comment: No, you'd need to state explicitly all the fields you want to concatenate; "*" won't do.

Answer (score 0):

Why the inner join, if you just want the subject names?

```
SELECT subject
FROM lesson
```

Now, if you want subjects that have at least one lesson, then you could simply do

```
SELECT DISTINCT subject
FROM lesson
INNER JOIN subjects ON subject.id = lesson.subject
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are hoping for one record per person, that is per `name`.

Here's a way to do that:

```
      SELECT name, count(*) subject_count
        FROM lesson 
  INNER JOIN subjects ON subject.id = lesson.subject
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY name
```

If you need the subjects shown in the record by name, try this:

```
      SELECT name, 
             count(*) subject_count,
             group_concat(subject) subjects
        FROM lesson 
  INNER JOIN subjects ON subject.id = lesson.subject
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY name
```